# MongoDB isConnected function to return boolean

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I found this function as I was looking for a way to know if the db connection is already active:

```
function isConnected() {
  return !!client && !!client.topology && client.topology.isConnected()
}
```

But it returns `Connected Client:1` or nothing at all and what I need is a straight `true or false or 1 or 0`.

How can I do that for mongodb 4.2.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
const mongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

function isConnected(client) {
  if (client && client.topology && client.topology.isConnected()) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

mongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost/database', function(error, client) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
    process.exit(1);
  } else {
    console.log(isConnected(client));
    process.exit(0);
  }
});
```